# Why does the compiler initialise these values?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In the following class when I construct an instance the compiler sets all the values to 0xcdcdcd which is Visual Studio compiler's initialisation value for unitialised memory.

```
class CommandBufferObject2
{
public:
    char* mypointer;

    int shared_reference_count;

    char* fbo;
    char* vk_buffer_handle;
    char* parent_cmd_pool;
    bool bIsSecondary;
    int current_subpass;
    char* bound_pipeline;

};



int main()
{
    auto* p2 = new CommandBufferObject2;
// ALL VALUES ARE UNITIALISED 0xcdcdcdcd
}
```

However when I initialise the last member:

```
class CommandBufferObject2
{
public:
    char* mypointer;

    int shared_reference_count;

    char* fbo;
    char* vk_buffer_handle;
    char* parent_cmd_pool;
    bool bIsSecondary;
    int current_subpass;
    char* bound_pipeline = nullptr; // here

};
```

Now every when I construct the object all the values are null, every single member. Why does this happen? I am on Visual Studio Version 17.7.6. Interestingly I built the project again in another Visual Studio project, and this doesn't happen, only the actual variable I set to nullptr is zeroed out. This makes me think that it's a setting of some sort, but I have no idea what's happening.

Comment: uninitialized values are.. uninitialized, when you read them, you have UB.

Comment: @Jarod42 that doesn't explain why the compiler would choose to stop initializing them with `0xcdcdcd` just because 1 member is initialized explicitly. I would have expected the other members to keep being initialized to `0xcdcdcd` if the project debug settings haven't changed.

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you compile it in release-mode instead?

Comment: I was able to duplicate this with VS 2022 Version 17.7.6 using this program https://godbolt.org/z/doYv1eW1v I don't see it in the godbolt assembly but locally for CB2 there's a function called `CB2::__autoclassinit2` that seems to be what is setting the whole thing to 0. `mov rcx, QWORD PTR classSize$[rbp] rep stosb`

Comment: @RetiredNinja Why does it do this?